# How to count an array inside an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

For example:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Test
        [slug] => test
        [services] => Array
            (
               [0] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => test
                   )
               [1] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => test
                   )
               [2] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => test
                   )
               [3] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => test
                   )
            )    
     )   
[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => Test
        [slug] => test
        [services] => Array
            (
               [0] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => test
                   )
               [1] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => test
                   )
               [2] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => test
                   )
               [3] => Array
                   (
                       [name] => test
                   )
            )    
     )
```

This is simply dummy data, however I want to count the amount of services that are inside each array but I'm looking for an efficient way.

Now the way I was going to do this was:

```
foreach($arrayAbove as $array){

    $i = 0;
    foreach($array['services'] as $array){
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach($arrayAbove as $array){

    $i = count($array['services']);
    print_r($i);
}
```

if you want overall count:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arrayAbove as $array){

     $i += count($array['services']);
}
print_r($i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fun way:

```
$result = array_reduce($array, function($c, $v) { return $c + count($v['services']); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP `sizeof()` Function](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_sizeof.asp)

```
foreach($arrayAbove as $array){

    $sub_array = sizeof($array['services']);           
    $total = $total + $sub_array;
}

echo 'Sub Array count is : '.$total;
```

Comment: @Random size of gives the count

Comment: actually `$total = $total + $sub_array;` contain count

Comment: @Random I suppose that depends on what you mean by "have to." You will get a notice if you don't, but it will still work.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yeah, if you can avoid a notice by adding a line, you **have to** do it, imo, to clear up logs... :)